# Apply afterwards customization to an already existing Angular app

Tags: angular, angular5

Here's the use case.

I have an Angular application which does things and is "general-purpose" for most of the customers I sell it to.
However, some customers have special needs and I must be able to add some features just for the app I'm going to sell to them.
Of course I don't want to duplicate the codebase of the app every time so I'm here asking: **is there a way to manage drop-in customization in an already existing core app?**

Creating only one App which works well for all customers doesn't seem to be feasible (of course it would be the first path to follow).
My thougths about this topic lead to the concept of creating a "core" module, then creating a new app for every customer requiring first the core, then the customization module.

Something like this

`imports: [
    CoreAppModule,
    CustomizationModule,
  ],`

In this way the decoupling will be optimal and everything is ok if the new features I'm adding are used separately from the ones of the core, but what happens if I want to **override** one of the components in the core module?

For example, if the core module exposes a ButtonComponent which says "Hello" when pressing a button and I need to customize it adding a second button which says "Hey!", I would obviously extend the provided ButtonComponent. But how can I tell the app to use *this* component instead of the base ButtonComponent wherever the first one was called?
I read around that two components with the same name cannot exists, Angular would complain.

Probably something can be achieved using components dynamic injection programmatically but it seems a "dirty" way to manage it and I'm not even sure it's actually possible.
Is there some kind of ***override system*** build-in into Angular module/component/provider management for this case of scenario?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619409/1160794

Comment: Yeah, it seems like an interesting way of doing it, ty.
I'm open to other ideas too